# Node JS error when I run 'npm start', maybe KrakenJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, kraken.js

When I try to run my app with 'npm start' it throws this error. I've updated Node and NPM but the error still throwing this error. I'm wondering if their is an issue with KrakenJS?

Thanks in advance

```html
> node server.js

Mon, 11 Apr 2016 13:41:08 GMT uncaughtException listen EADDRINUSE :::8000
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:913:20)
    at Server.__dirname.Server.Server._listen2 (net.js:1230:14)
    at listen (net.js:1266:10)
    at Server.__dirname.Server.Server.listen (net.js:1362:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../server.js:14:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! testapp@0.1.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the testapp@0.1.0 start script 'node server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the testapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs testapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls testapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: What shows up if you navigate to `http://localhost:8000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something is already listening on port 8000. Try running:

```
lsof -i:8000
```

and see if it lists the process. Also you can check `http://localhost:8000`

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though your trying to run the server on port 8000 and something is already using it.

```
Mon, 11 Apr 2016 13:41:08 GMT uncaughtException listen EADDRINUSE :::8000
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8000
```

Try selecting a different port for your server or running some diagnostics to see if you have something bound on 8000.

Comment: Oh yes how embarrassing! I had another terminal window open and hidden. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `EADDRINUSE` error tells you that the used port is allready used by another program and can't be used by your application.
Try checking for applications on that port or just change the port itself.